# Copy and paste data from one sheet to another sheet(s) based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have orders everyday to put on different worksheets according to the column "delivery provider" and "channel".
[image: image description here]

I had created a userform before but I have to divide my data sheet into several sheets according to the delivery provider and channel, then copy and paste all the columns one by one to each sheet with the code

```
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr).Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("B2")
```

I have many providers (6 or more) which makes it time consuming.

How can I copy and paste them into the desired worksheets according to the two columns.

I came across and idea that I can CONST each column in "data" as source column, and CONST each column in "ems_by_sea" and others as target/destination colunm, then do the FOR/NEXT statement. But I have no idea how to CONST at different worksheets.

```
const firstrow = 2
const soucol_provider = sh1.cells("E"), soucol_channel = sh1.cells("F")
```

I tried to do it by this but VBA responds with error

```vb
Application.screenupdating = False
For i = firstrow to lr
If Sh1.Cells(i, soucol_provider).Value = "EMS" and Sh1.Cells(i, soucol_channel).Value = "by air" Then 
    #copy and paste the data in current row to the sheet"ems_by_air'
nex i
```

It's not just copy and paste the exact data to the sheets since the column order in each sheet is different.

Comment: As I left an answer as a suggested path forward, the answer to your question about `const` is that you cannot set an object to constant.  You could `const` a string, e.g., the name of a sheet, then use that, though I personally feel that determining and setting a sheet via `select` is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your scope, you could `select` a case for your destination spreadsheet, e.g.:

```
dim destSheet as worksheet
Select case true
    case deliveryProvider = "X" and channel="Y"
        set destSheet = sheets(1)
    case deliveryProvider = "A" and channel="B"
        set destSheet = sheets(2)
End select
With destSheet
    'use .notation
End with
```

You can set up conditions as you deem fit, to account for your number of factors/variables.

Comment: Thank you so much Cyril for the advice. I will give it a try first